# Why won't fluent-ffmpeg respect the audioBitrate?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have:

```
            ffmpeg(stream)
                .audioBitrate(8)
                .save(outputFilename)
                .on('progress', p => {
                    console.log(`${p.targetSize}kb downloaded`);
                })
                .on('end', resolve)
                .on('error', reject)
```

And it saves the file, but it still has a 48KHz sample rate. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your environment, and I have found the error. [`.audioBitrate`](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#audiobitratebitrate-set-audio-bitrate) is influencing the quality of the audio's output (See this [8k file](https://siasky.net/_Aa2v-DVFSrLfNS0iU3--unIHa-NtqEKwcpLdwV7R0C2Vg) versus [the original](https://siasky.net/_Ajt6UjPn7fGtbnk34LQ0fUn13tm5fBJhCIJXKNXFcFqBA)), whereas [`.audioFrequency`](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#audiofrequencyfreq-set-audio-frequency) influences the sample rate.

Spectrum analysis from Spek backs up these changes (left: original; right: `.audioBitrate(8).audioFrequency(11025)`.
[image: Spectrum]

Please let me know if this solves your issue.

// Full code

```
ffmpeg("./cat_kfc.mp4")
    .audioBitrate(8)
    .audioFrequency(11025)
    .save("./output.mp4")
    .on('progress', p => {
        console.log(`${p.targetSize}kb downloaded`);
    })
    .on('end', ()=>console.log("Done!"))
    .on('error', ()=>console.log("ERROR!"))
```